# Lex/yacc only detecting one token

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am trying to write a LaTeX parser using lex and yacc but I am struggling. Here is my lexer:

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%%
^\\begin\{.*\} {return BEG;}
%%

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
```

and here is my parser:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void yyerror(char *s);
int yylex();
extern FILE *yyin;
%}

%token BEG

%%
beg: BEG {printf("Hello world\n");}
%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong number of arguments provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!yyin) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not a valid filename\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if I run this on the LaTeX snippet

```
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    x = 3
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I get

```
Hello world

syntax error
```

It seems like the parser is only seeing one `\begin` pattern, instead of two. Why is that? I really don't see why. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I tried something like

```
lines: line
     | lines line
     ;
line: beg '\n'
    | ID '\n'
    ;
beg: BEG {printf("Hello world\n");}
   ;
```

where ID corresponds to the regex `.*`, but I get the same error.

Comment: It's been a while, but I don't think `.` matches with a newline character. You need to account for `\n`.

Comment: It's not that the parser only sees one `BEGIN` token. It only *expects* one (because your grammar only  matches one). It sees both, that's why you get the syntax error.

Comment: I still don't get it. I have edited my question if you want to take a look.

Comment: @fresh Your parser says that a document is just a BEG and nothing else. So it expects BEG followed by YYEOF. What it sees is BEG followed by BEG which is not valid according to your grammar.

Comment: What about ID? That should match any line.

Comment: That is literally all the code I have, except for the fact that I added ```.* return ID;``` in the lexer.

Comment: Does your lexer ever return '\n' ?

Comment: Yeah sorry now I also have ```%token BEG ID``` in the parser. Should I add something like ```\n return EOL;``` in the lexer (and define EOL in the parser)?

Comment: Yot don't really need to define EOL, you can just return `\n`, but yes, this is the direction.

Comment: Well you told the parser to expect a \n so if the lexer outputs something other than \n it's a syntax error, as you know. The parser parses the output of the lexer, not the actual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lexer:**

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
%}

%%
^\\begin\{.*\} {return BEG;}
\n {
        return  *yytext;
    }
%%

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
```

**Parserx:**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void yyerror(char *s);
int yylex();
extern FILE *yyin;
%}

%token BEG
%start beg
%%
beg: BEG '\n' {printf("Hello world\n");}
%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong number of arguments provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!yyin) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not a valid filename\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

This above code is as much as I can remember, And I would also suggest you to first to make note of what kind of tokens you are expecting and grammar based on  what you actually want to do with those tokens.

In following grammar:

```
lines: line
     | lines line
     ;
line: beg '\n'
    | ID '\n'
    ;
beg: BEG {printf("Hello world\n");}
   ;
```

`lines` is a start variable, with a set of non-terminals as lines, line, and beg, and terminals (tokens) ID, BEG, '\n'. Though this grammar does not make any sense since it is based on your lexer because your lexer is also supposed to return these tokens.

The following grammar means you have a start token as `beg` and you are getting a token `BEG` and a token `'\n'`. Based on which you are printing `'Hello World'`. Though I don't really know how this will proceed.

```
beg: BEG '\n'  {printf("Hello world\n");}
```